# Javascript - any kind of rest operator that skips undefined properties?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this:

```
var filters = {a: 1, b: undefined}
```

And I want this:

```
{ a:1 }
```

Is there any way of getting the object above by using modern Javascript features like `{...filters}` ?

Answer (score 4):

Unless you know in advance a *singular* property which is `undefined`, it's not possible with rest syntax, or anything new like that, though you *can* achieve it by serializing and deserializing the object. The code is short, but it's inelegant and only works when everything in the object is serializable:

```js
var filters = {a: 1, b: undefined};
var filtersNoUndef = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(filters));
console.log(filtersNoUndef);
```

Or, of course, you can iterate over the properties manually:

```js
var filters = {a: 1, b: undefined};
const filtersNoUndef = { ...filters };
Object.entries(filtersNoUndef).forEach(([key, val]) => {
  if (val === undefined) {
    delete filtersNoUndef[key];
  }
});
console.log(filtersNoUndef);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative using the function `reduce`

```js
let filters = {a: 1, b: undefined};
let result = Object.entries(filters).reduce((a, [key, value]) => value === undefined ? a : Object.assign(a, {[key]: value}), Object.create(null));

console.log(result);
```